# Deleting a record based on only the year in the date in mysql

Tags: mysql

Say I need to delete any course records with a 'DateOffered' Year of 2004, can anyone explain how I would do this?

*I am using a 'date' data type for the DateOffered column.

Here is my table: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Courses WHERE year(DateOffered) = 2004
```

Just in case your date column isn't formatted properly, before trying to run that, I would make sure the correct rows are being pulled by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE year(DateOffered) = 2004
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: This query will not use indexes. It's much better to have where clause specified as "DateOffered >= '2004-01-01' AND DateOffered <= '2004-12-31'"

Comment: You're right in the case that the database has a large number of rows. But in his case with 20 rows, I think he would waste way more time typing out that query than the time saved on running it.